# Convergent subsequence in $C^1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, limits, functions

We consider two closed interval in $\mathbb{R}$ : $[a,b]$ and $[c,d]$. Moreover, let us consider a sequence $\{f_{n}\}_{n = 1}^{\infty}$ uniformly bounded in $C^1([a,b]\times [c,d])$. My question is: Is there exist a subsequence $\{f_{n_{j}}\}_{j = 1}^{\infty}$ and $f \in C^{1}([a,b]\times [c,d])$ such that
$f_{n_{j}}$ converges to $f$ in the  **weak** our $\mbox{weak}^{*}$ sense?

Answer (score 0):

You need the Eberlein-Smuljan Theorem. It states the following:

Let X be a Banach space. Then every bounded sequence in X has a weakly convergent subsequence.

The space $C^1([a,b]\times[c,d])$ is a Banach space, so you get the weakly convergent subsequence directly from the theorem. As the space is banach, the limit $f$ obviously is an element of your space.